# Jsoup: Session expires after some time

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup

I have writeen a Java code using Jsoup or extracting some data out of the website https://widgets.vodafone.com. This I did by reading the headers using the Firefox addon 'Live HTTP Headers' and passing them while logging in. Though it works perfectly, the session expires every two days. And the main motto of me writing this code (which was its complete automation) is still not met.

The code starts working again if I relogin and update the code with a new 'authentication id' and 'cookie id'.

Can someone please tell me how I can make it work.

P.S. I have done the same for the site developer.getjar.com and it works like a charm. Hasn't given me any issues till now.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Some cookies have a expire date. There's really nothing you can do about it, but to control the HTTP 403 exception. When it happens, redo the "login" process.

```
loginMethod();

while(true) {

    if(expired())
        loginMethod();

    if(processingOver())
        break;

    //Processing

}
```

Comment: It redirects me to a page which says "Your sesion has expired" :(
When I see the expiration date for the cookie while using Live HTTP Headers, is a month later.. That's why I couldn't understand why it's happening so

Comment: Just edited my answer to make it clearer. As you have not informed much about the code, I tried to name the methods in an understandable way.

Comment: I know the way I have presented the question is not clear but since I don't own the code (I work in an IT firm) I cannot patse it over here. But I'll try to make it clearer. Initially, I log in using firefox and note down the cookie Id and the authentication token (which is exclusive to the Vodafone site) among other data. These are the ones which expire as I have to change them whenever I am not able to login using the code. If I log out of the site in firefox, the cookie ID and authentication token become useless and I have to change the again. So I just simply close the window.

Comment: While connecting using jsoup, I pass these tow along with the username and password. I parse the page and retrieve the links I need for further processing. When the processing is over, I donot log out as it renders the cookie useless. I simply exit the program. This works of two days at most after which I have to put in the new cookie ID and authentication token.

Comment: When it is unable to log in, it redirects me to the login page with the caption "Your session has expired" on the top. You can make dummy credentials and try it out if you have the time so that whatever I'm saying is clear. I know it's too much to ask but it is difficult for me to post the code.